# <input type ="button"> me envía el formulario. ¿Cómo lo evito?

Tags: javascript, html, botón

Tengo el siguiente input de tipo "button" el cual llama a una función javascript. Lo que me ocurre es que una vez la llama, borra todos los campos del formulario. Parece que está haciendo un "clear" o un "submit". He buscado en el foro varias preguntas relacionadas y en todas dice que hay que especificar que sea de tipo button ya que si no se pone nada, lo considera submit por defecto.

Aquí os dejo el código de mi botón. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que después de ejecutar la función javascript no me borre del formulario lo que había escrito antes? Gracias!!

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>
      <input type="button" value="VER" name="verPlantilla" id="verPlantilla" onclick="mostrarPlantill(id.value);">
```

Comment: Agrega el código de la función JS por favor

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba lo siguiente y me comentas porfavor

```
<a type="button" id="verPlantilla" onclick="mostrarPlantill(this.id);">VER </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá usando simplemente un botón como:

```
<button id="verPlantilla" onclick="mostrarPlantill(id.value);">VER</button>
```